# Custom Field Search

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, search

I'm trying to create a custom search form that searches a custom post type that I have created.

The form would need to search two custom taxonomies (similar to tags and categories) and the body text of the post.

There would be a search input that would search the body text and tags and a dropdown that would filter by category (Any, Category 1, Category 2, Category 3).

What kind of templates would I need to make and what kind of code would this require?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Sorry, this is not a place where you can post a wish list for code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pre_get_posts to filter search results:

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'custom_post_type_name');
      $query->set('cat', intval($_POST['cat']); // assuming you have a select with categories with name "cat" 
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```